# Python type hint for generic in a more tricky way

Tags: python, generics, python-typing

Suppose I have a class `Number`:

```py
from typing import TypeVar, Generic

T = TypeVar('T')

class Number(Generic[T]):
    value: T
```

where `T` is a type variable, which can be `int`, `float`, `Decimal`, `Fraction`, etc.

Now I want to define some methods, like `__add__`. In simple way, we may set parameters and return-value the same type as value, like:

```py
class Number(Generic[T]):
    value: T
    def __add__(self, other: T) -> T: ...
```

However, when things like `int + float`, which are addable, but the type-hint above doesn't work.

the question is: how can the type-hint-system gets the infomation of the `T`, telling that only some types (not only `T`, or even `T` can't be) can operate with type `T`, like:

```py
class Number(Generic[T]):
    value: T
    def __add__(self, other: T_addable) -> T_addition_result: ...
```

I tried using `Protocol`, `covariant`, `contravariant`

```py
from typing import TypeVar, Protocol, runtime_checkable

T = TypeVar("T")
T_co = TypeVar("T_co", covariant=True)
T_contra = TypeVar("T_contra", contravariant=True)

@runtime_checkable
class SupportsAdd(Protocol[T_contra, T_co]):
    __slots__ = ()
    def __add__(self, x: T_contra) -> T_co: ...
```

but this cannot determine `T_contra` and `T_co` from `T`. Usually this only be used as `SupportsAdd[Any, Any]`, which can't help.

Answer (score 0):

The first issue is that `T` is unbound. It can be anything, you could construct a `Number[str]` or `Number[list[set[int]] | dict[tuple[int, int], str]]`...

There are two (three, if you count constraint typevariables like `AnyStr`) ways to constrain it:

1. Make the type variable bound to the most derived supertype. Sadly, that supertype of all numeric types, `numbers.Number`, isn't supported by mypy.
2. Make use of protocols, like you already have.

Here's where I started:

```
T = TypeVar('T')

class SupportsAdd(Protocol[T]):
    def __add__(self, other: T) -> T: ...

class Number(Generic[T]):
    value: SupportsAdd[T]
    def __init__(self, value: SupportsAdd[T]) -> None:
        self.value = value
    def __add__(self, other: T) -> T:
        return self.value + other
```

Now, that almost worked, except I needed to explicitly denote `T`:

```
n = Number[float](3)

reveal_type(n + 1.0) # float
```

... and it didn't always give the desired answer:

```
reveal_type(n + 1) # float, runtime type: int
```

Alright, so maybe we can split `T` into a covariant and contravariant part, as you wrote. That didn't pan out for me. Neither did any of the other things I could think of.

That's when I decided to take a step back. What is the source of the complexity here?

The thing about the numeric types is that they're special cased by tools like mypy.

Operators like `__add__` are typed only as `(Self, Self) -> Self`, and the ability to mix and match numeric types are implemented by having rules like "`int` is assignable to `float`", "`float` is assignable to `complex`", and so on. So if you do `3 + 4.2`, mypy sees it as `3` being assigned to a float, then having `float + float`, rather than it being `int + float`.

So the problem is that your `Number` class isn't likewise special cased: you can't make `Number[int]` assignable to `Number[float]` in general. Basically, you cannot construct a class definition such that for an instance `n` both `assert_type(n + 1.0, float)` and `assert_type(n + 1, int)` pass.

I'd love to be proven wrong, but I can't see any way around this.

Comment: You can support any combination known in advance, just with a bunch of overloads:) Here's what numpy [does](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/71ab90631eed8667b33bf80ffde761df0adff9b7/numpy/__init__.pyi#L1979) (and [this](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/71ab90631eed8667b33bf80ffde761df0adff9b7/numpy/_typing/_callable.pyi#L181))